# Slow chess bot, need to go faster

Tags: python, algorithm, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have created a chess bot using minimax and alpha beta pruning, along it I have also created a GUI. But my bot can't go very deep before becoming extremely slow. Already in depth 4 it can take up to 40-50 seconds to find a move.

The algorithm looks like this:

```
def minimax(depth,board, alpha, beta, is_max):
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluation(board)
    leg_moves = board.legal_moves
    if is_max:
        value = -9999
        for i_move in leg_moves:
            move = chess.Move.from_uci(str(i_move))
            board.push(move)
            value = max(value, minimax(depth - 1, board, alpha, beta, False))
            board.pop()
            alpha = max(alpha, value)
            if beta <= alpha:
                return value
        return value
    else:
        value = 9999
        for i_move in leg_moves:
            move = chess.Move.from_uci(str(i_move))
            board.push(move)
            value = min(value, minimax(depth - 1, board, alpha, beta, True))
            board.pop()
            beta = min(beta, value)
            if(beta <= alpha):
                return value
        return value
```

To summarize, how do I make it faster?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? What's the bottleneck? In most cases the problem is a slow algorithm and not a slow code. You are trying all possible legal moves. AFAIK chess engines use a heuristic.

Comment: Another big factor is that it is possible to reach the same position by multiple sequences of moves, so there is benefit to caching the analysis for positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing a Negamax function instead of Minimax will make future efficiency implementations much easier as a start, it will also make the code look cleaner:

```
def negamax(depth, board, alpha, beta, color):
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluation(board)
    leg_moves = board.legal_moves
    for i_move in leg_moves:
        move = chess.Move.from_uci(str(i_move))
        board.push(move)
        value = -negamax(depth - 1, board, -beta, -alpha, -color)
        board.pop()
        alpha = max(alpha, value)
        if beta <= alpha:
            return value
     return value
```

Then you might want to look into concepts such as sorting the moves before going into the recursive function, since you will get a beta cutoff much faster that way and not having to look through as many moves. Then you can also implement for example a transposition table (with iterative deepening), null moves and late move reduction.

You probably also want to look at your move generation and see if you can make it any faster. For example, what board representation do you use?

I have made a chess engine in Python which is not at all top notch. It goes to depth 6 in about 15 seconds and you can find the code here for inspiration: [Affinity Chess](https://github.com/eligolf/affinity_chess). It uses a 1D board representation, but a bitboard representation would be even faster.

I would also highly recommend looking at [www.chessprogramming.org](http://www.chessprogramming.org), there is lots of really nice information there.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I implemented this and also fixed the evaluation function. Now the bot can actually go 1 depth further. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors for make the algorithm fast adding more standard features of chess programs. But only 4 moves and so much time is not normal with your source code. How do you generate the moves? You should not ask about them via the UCI protocol, instead try to generate them really fast. In particular do not search about figures on the board, instead organize there positions in a list and add/remove them if they are taken from the board.

Maybe your evaluation function is slow. If you only take care of the values of the pieces, then have a variable to hold the difference of the colours and only update it if a piece is taken or restore. So the evaluation needs nearly no time anymore.

In a java program i reach a depth of 7 in 4s with implementing this details without using methods like hashtables.